# python subprocess dd and stdout

Tags: python, subprocess, dd

I am using subprocess to create a random file from /dev/random using unix dd. Now, if i want the data output of dd to be written to a file instead of stdout. so here's the code am using,

```
import subprocess
out_fd = open('test_file','w')
def os_system_dd():
   global out_fd
   out_fd.write("executing the time dd command\n")
   cmd_list = ['time','dd','if=/dev/random', 'of=/home/anand/sys_entropy_random', 'bs=1M' ,'count=5']
   a = subprocess.Popen(cmd_list,stdout=out_fd)
   a.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   os_system_dd()
```

This doesn't print the dd output to the file and instead prints it in the stdout. 
Is this a specific functionality of dd command?  Or am i missing some thing about how subprocess works?

Comment: +1 For succinct code and using a list to construct the argument. However, I can't reproduce your problem here; your code works fine. Does your problem still occur if the whole code is `subprocess.Popen(['time','dd','if=/dev/random', 'of=sys_entropy_random', 'bs=1M' ,'count=5']).communicate()` ?

Comment: Well, i tried this 
`code` a = subprocess.Popen(['time','dd','if=/dev/random', 'of=/home/anand/sys_entropy_random', 'bs=1M' ,'count=5'],stdout=out_fd) `code`
and still get the same error. Using communicate() may solve my problem, but i was trying to avoid the extra explicit write from python. will try and update it though.

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood the question. Answered - simply redirect stderr instead of stdout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dd` outputs its debugging information on stderr, not stdout:

```
import subprocess
out_fd = open('test_file','w')
def os_system_dd():
   out_fd.write("executing the time dd command\n")
   cmd_list = ['time','dd','if=/dev/random', 'of=/home/anand/sys_entropy_random',
                           'bs=1M' ,'count=5']
   a = subprocess.Popen(cmd_list,stderr=out_fd) # notice stderr
   a.communicate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   os_system_dd()
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason nothing gets written in the file is because its written to stderr. Redirect stderr and you will get the result.

```
import subprocess
out_fd = open('test_file','w')
def os_system_dd():
   global out_fd
   out_fd.write("executing the time dd command\n")
   cmd_list = ['date'] #Your list
   a = subprocess.Popen(cmd_list,stdout=out_fd, stderr=out_fd)
   a.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   os_system_dd()
```

Also, flush the buffer after writing "executing the time..."

Comment: `shell=True` just makes the code run slower and more error-prone. Why would you want to use it?

Comment: My bad. I tried adding different things till it worked. Now I realize that there was nothing wrong with his code except that stderr redirection. Updating my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @phihag I don't think that the slowdown is noticeable in any way. And if the command line is hard coded, there is noothing wrong with `shell=True` (except that it leaves a little bad smell). If it was a dynaming string, it would be criminal indeed...